# NSMenuItem become disable with parameter selector

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have a menu in which i'm adding NSMenuItem progmatically.NSMenuItem works fine with

```
@selector(onClickProject)
```

but with

```
@selector(onClickProject:)
```

NSMenuItem becomes disabled

here is the code

```
 NSMenuItem *project = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i - %@",i + 1,[self.arrayProjects[i] objectForKey:@"p_ProjectTitle"]] action:@selector(onClickProject:) keyEquivalent:@""];
```

i'm using

```
-(void)onClickProject:(id)Sender
```

for

```
@selector(onClickProject:)
```

and

```
-(void)onClickProject
```

for

```
@selector(onClickProject)
```

and of-course i was using one at a time.means i was editing the same function

Comment: Does your method onClickProject take a parameter? It matters whether you need the colon or not.

Comment: i added and removed based on :

Comment: -(void)onClickProject:(id)Sender for @selector(onClickProject:)

Comment: and 
 
-(void)onClickProject for @selector(onClickProject)

Comment: and of-course i was using one at a time.means i was editing the same function

Comment: Post your code in the Q, not in the comments.

Comment: Did you set the target?